# Upgrading to EF 6 and now getting a LINQ error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, datetime

I was using Entity Framework 4 or 5, and my code worked fine. I have now upgraded to Entity Framework 6 and I get the following error

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime] TruncateTime(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

```
 public IEnumerable<DateTimeAndVisitCount> GetRecentVisitsByDay(int numberOfDays)
    {

        var fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-numberOfDays);
        var result = (from d in this.DataContext.VisitDetail
                      where d.DateTime >= fromDate
                      group d by (DateTime)EntityFunctions.TruncateTime((DateTime)d.DateTime) into g
                      select new DateTimeAndVisitCount()
                      {
                          DateTime = (DateTime)g.Key,
                          Count = g.Count()
                      });

        return result;

    }
```

In the above object, this.DataContext.VisitDetail, I will point out that VisitDetail.DateTime does NOT accept nulls.

I've tried to cast everything to `DateTime` as you can see, but the same error message.

How do I appease Entity Framework 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EntityFunctions` has been replaced by [DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in Entity Framework v6.0.

You should change `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` to `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` and remove `System.Data.Entity` from the project.